# Complexity Analysis

Tags: java, complexity-theory

I have tried  to compute this complexity, but I couldn't

I thought it will be an infinite loop, but my instructor gave me this problem as a homework and asked me to find the complexity and how many time statement1 & statement2 will be executed .

Can any one help me ?

```
   sum = 0;
         for (i=1; i<=n; i*=2) {
           for (j=1; j<=i; j++)
             sum++; // MyStatement1
           for (k=1; j<=n; k++)
             sum++; // MyStatement2
    }
```

Comment: @sanbhat O(2n^2) is O(n^2) and no...

Comment: Did you really mean to test `j<=n`?

Comment: for (k=1; j<=n; k++) no check for k will loop for infinite since for loop for (j=1; j<=i; j++) j is always less equal to than n(since i<=n)

Comment: I thought it will be an infinite loop, but my instructor gave me this problem as a homework and asked me to find the complexity and how many time statement1 & statement2 will be executed

Comment: If you think statement 2 repeats forever that's your business. There's no need to second guess yourself and ask for help with such homework, though I agree.

Answer (score 1):

When he is talking about Complexity if he is referring to the number of branches (cyclomatic) I suppose it's either 3 or 6 depending on if he counts the implicit "If" test to end a for loop or not (I can't remember, but I think it would be 6).

As for the number of times the statements will be executed, it must be based on n's initial value.  It looks like n=1 executes the first statement once and skips the second, but for other positive values--well--trace it through and see what happens.

Sometimes it helps to play "Computer" and write down the values of N, J, K, I, ... on a piece of paper.